# how to let one column keep two decimal point, another column` without decimal point(int) in dataframe/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposed I have both `sum` and `mean` value in `dataframe`, how to let `difference` column keep two decimal point, and `value_a` and `value_b` keep int(without decimal point)

```py
df.columns=['value_a','value_b','name','up_or_down','difference']

df1 = df.agg({'value_a':'sum', 'value_b':'sum', 'difference':'mean'}).to_frame('Total').T

df = pd.concat([df1,df])
print (df.head())
                value_a  value_b  difference            name up_or_down
Total             27.56    25.04   -0.035405             NaN        NaN
2021-project11     1.43     3.48    0.05  2021-project11         up
2021-project1      2.62     3.56   -0.06   2021-project1       down
2021-project2      5.51     2.47   -0.3   2021-project2       down
2021-porject3      5.37     2.34   -0.12   2021-porject3       down
```

My except output is as below:

```
                value_a  value_b  difference            name up_or_down
Total             13    10   -0.035            NaN        NaN
2021-project11     1     3    0.05  2021-project11         up
2021-project1      2     3   -0.06   2021-project1       down
2021-project2      5     2   -0.30   2021-project2       down
2021-porject3      5     2   -0.12   2021-porject3       down
```

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: yes, I always added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and for 2 decimals [`DataFrame.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), in your expected output data are 3 decimals in first row, it is not possible, need same decimal in column:

```
df = df.astype({'value_a':int, 'value_b':int})
df1 = df.agg({'value_a':'sum', 'value_b':'sum', 'difference':'mean'}).to_frame('Total').T
df = pd.concat([df1,df]).round({'difference': 2})
print (df)
```

Comment: If use round, 0.3 is still 0.3, can I use decimal? then I can get `0.30`

Comment: @QueenElsa - For me working correct, for you last `0` are removed? For each values like `0.3`, `0.1`, `-0.3` ?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I updated my data

Comment: When I use `pd.pivot_table`, all styles were failed, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @QueenElsa - hmmm, what failed? Integers or `difference` ? How looks your pivot_table code?

Comment: `df=pd.pivot_table(df,index=[u'code'],columns=[u'name'],
                                    values=[u'value_a','value_b','difference'])`

Comment: I wrote lots of styles like this `df.astype({'value_a':int, 'value_b':int})` in a function, before `pd.pivot_table`, everything is fine, but If I use `pd.pivot_table`, all data keep two decimal.

Comment: @QueenElsa - I see. Reason is pivot_table if has at least one float column then `'break'` all columns to floats :(

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? Thanks so much for your answer, I can ask a new question if you need.

Comment: @QueenElsa - hmmm, you need same type in column. So if there are mixed integers and NaNs or integers, NaNs ans floats in some column get `floats` Can you test how working `df=pd.pivot_table(df,index=[u'code'],columns=[u'name'],                                     values=[u'value_a','value_b','difference'], fill_value=0)` ?